# Attempting to modify CSV value based on the input received

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Below is an example of the code, essentially I am taking input received and attempting to modify an existing CSV value. The problem is the code runs and produces the "print" output as expected, but the values are not being modified to "True" or "False" based on the if and else statements:

```py
def test():
    sn_cmn = pd.read_csv('cmn_location.csv')
    wan = re.findall(r'Tunnel12', str(router_output)) or re.findall(r'Tunnel13', str(router_output))
    hostname = re.search(r'...-....-R.', str(router_output))
    hostname_string = str(hostname)
    site_code = hostname_string[-13:-10]

    if wan == ['Tunnel12'] or wan == ['Tunnel13']:
        answer = 'Yes'
        if answer == 'Yes':
            for site in sn_cmn.u_site_code:
                sn_cmn.loc[sn_cmn['u_site_code'] == site_code, 'u_iwan_3'] = 'TRUE'

    else:
        for site in sn_cmn.u_site_code:
            sn_cmn.loc[sn_cmn['u_site_code'] == site_code, 'u_iwan_3'] = 'FALSE'

    sn_cmn.to_csv('new_cmn_location.csv')
```

Comment: It is unclear where some of your variables are defined.  For instance, `router_output` seems to be referenced before assignment.  I assume it's a global variable that was defined outside of your function but your post is lacking sufficient code to determine if that's correct.

Comment: I agree with @RagingRoosevelt. For instance, it's unclear whether `wan` is expected to contain a single element (as your code suggests). Adding example values for `wan` would help. As a general rule, I would check whether `wan` is indeed a list with a single element, and whether the conditions `sn_cmn['u_site_code'] == site_code` are ever True.

Comment: router_output is simply a variable that is taking command output from a router. 
        router_output = connection.recv(65535). Based on router_output the command should return a "Tunnel12", "Tunnel13", or neither and the host mane of the router typically something along the lines of "ATL-4444-R2", this is where the hostname and site_code variables comes into play. The csv only contains the first 3 letters of the hostname ex ATL. This has been confirmed to working as expected. The ATL from the hostname variable is stored as the site_code variable.

Comment: I want to use this variable to search on a specific row in the csv that is listed under the column "u_site_code" . Once it finds the row with the correct site code, I want to modify a specific column "u_iwan_3" on that row based on the feedback of router_output, whether it contains "Tunnel12" or "Tunnel13". If it contains those two strings in the router_output change column "u_iwan_3" to TRUE.

Comment: One oddity is that you don't use the variable you create in the loop:
```
for site in sn_cmn.u_site_code:
    sn_cmn.loc[sn_cmn['u_site_code'] == site_code, 'u_iwan_3'] = 'FALSE'
```
You don't use `site`, but `site_code`. Maybe that's the cause?